# jQuery add HTML to links if they contain multiple keywords

Tags: jquery, string, indexof

I have a few links which I would like to append with the word "SALE" based on a string in found the link, and I have successfully used the code below. However, I'd like to be able to have the code look at more than one string if possible.

Currently, the word "SALE" is appended to the links that contain the string "SHIRT". I'd also like it to be applied to all links that contain "JACKET" as well.

Is there a way of doing this as an array?

```
<div>
    <div class="link"><a href="/products/WHITESHIRT">White Shirt</a></div>
    <div class="link"><a href="/products/BLACKSHIRT">Black Shirt</a></div>
    <div class="link"><a href="/products/GREENSHIRT">Green Shirt</a></div>
    <div class="link"><a href="/products/WHITESHORTS">White Shorts</a></div>
    <div class="link"><a href="/products/BLACKTROUSERS">Black Trousers</a></div>
    <div class="link"><a href="/products/YELLOWJACKET">Yellow Jacket</a></div>
</div>
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
<script>
$(".link a").each(function () {
    var href=$(this).prop('href');
    if (href.indexOf('SHIRT') > -1) {
    $(this).append(" SALE");
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Add `or` condition in your if statement i.e : `|| href.indexOf('JACKET') > -1`

Comment: FYI you can use `.includes(...)` instead of `.indexOf(...) > -1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can use Array `some` method

##### Array `some`

```
array.some(function(value, index, arr), this)
```

#### Try below Code

```js
var keywords = ['SHIRT', 'JACKET'];
$(".link a").each(function () {
    var href = $(this).prop('href');
    if (keywords.some(function (v) { return href.indexOf(v) >= 0; })) {
        $(this).append(" SALE");
    }
    console.log(keywords.some(function (v) { return href.includes(v) }))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="link"><a href="/products/WHITESHIRT">White Shirt</a></div>
    <div class="link"><a href="/products/BLACKSHIRT">Black Shirt</a></div>
    <div class="link"><a href="/products/GREENSHIRT">Green Shirt</a></div>
    <div class="link"><a href="/products/WHITESHORTS">White Shorts</a></div>
    <div class="link"><a href="/products/BLACKTROUSERS">Black Trousers</a></div>
    <div class="link"><a href="/products/YELLOWJACKET">Yellow Jacket</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of indexOf use `includes(...)` . Makes this part more readable.

Comment: Right but `includes` will compare href with the exact array elements.
So here **href="/products/WHITESHIRT"** so it will never compared. Is I'm correct?

Comment: No you are not correct. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: Yes but how we can check multiple values for `includes` ?
Please suggest or provide answer for this so. It would great knowledge for me too.

Comment: Similar to what you already have: `keywords.some(function (v) { return href.inlcudes(v) }`

Comment: @cloned this had produced error please [have a look once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRE3Y.png)

Comment: Because I had a type... `includes()` is correct, not `inlcudes()` :-D

Comment: Yes perfect I have logged it in console.